# List of all commits that modify a path and aren't merged into given branch

Tags: git

Given a specific branch and path, get a list of all commits that:

- Are not merged into branch
- Modify some file in the path

Manual inspection (e.g. `git log --all -- path/to`) is not an option - I want the full list of commits (or branches containing commits) that have unmerged changes.

`git branch --no-merge` is also no good, apparently it can't be limited to a path.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

```
git log --all --oneline ^my_branch -- path/to/my/stuff
```

Further, to get the names of branches containing such commits:

```
git log --all --oneline ^my_branch --pretty=format:%H -- path/to/my/stuff | xargs  git describe --contains --all
```